# How do I add a server control to an existing solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I want to add a server control to an existing web application but cannot figure out how to add the Server Control to a web page or show up in the Tool Box.  All the documentation seems to create the user control first and then add a web application to the solution and that works fine.  So how would I add a server control to an existing web application, and if possible within the same solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about dependencies.  I was able to get this working by adding server control project to the solution.  Building the server control project.  Then adding a dependency on the server control project to the web project.  Next, I built everything again then right-clicked in the *ToolBox* and chose *"select items"*, pointed it to the  *"/bin/debug/servercontrol.dll."*  Finally, I dragged the new toolbox item out.  I am sure that one or more of these steps in unnecessary, but it got everything working together.